# Why do two-beam interferometers have a relatively broad "fringe width" compared to single-beam interferometers?

Tags: optics, laser, interference, interferometry, photonics

I recently overheard someone discussing the basics of interferometry setups. They said that [two-beam interferometers](https://www.microscopyu.com/microscopy-basics/two-beam-interferometry) have a relatively broad "fringe width" compared to single-beam interferometers, and that this was superior for their experiment. My first thought was that this perhaps could be due to constructive interference from the two laser beams, but my understanding is that constructive interference doesn't change the *width* of the fringe, only the amplitude. So why do two-beam interferometers have a relatively broad "fringe width" compared to single-beam interferometers?